# Table storage of input (double datatype) stored differenty from debug to published MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

I have fully tested my MVC application in debug mode, but when final stage testing it (after publishing) I discovered the anomaly with the stored price value when using the published web app. The decimal point is missing now, it is a double when sent through as an entity and is displayed as a double in the table storage view in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. However it no longer has a decimal point and is now 2325 as opposed to 23,25. I have also tested it with a . decimal point. This is not an issue in the debug but has the same result.

[image: This is the input when testing my **debug** MVC application]
This is the input when testing my **debug** MVC application.

[image: This is the output from the **debug** test as viewed in table storage]
This is the output from the **debug** test as viewed in table storage.

[image: This is the identical input of my **published** MVC application (No changes)]
This is the identical input of my **published** MVC application (No changes).

[image: This is the output from my **published** app test as viewed in table storage]
This is the output from my **published** app test as viewed in table storage.

Here is my source code for the formatting in case it makes a difference but as it works with debug mode I don't consider it to be a formatting issue.

```
string price = Request["tbItemPrice"].ToString().Replace(".", ",").Replace("$", "");

ItemModel newItem = new ItemModel(inputImage.FileName, name, desc, Double.Parse(price));

TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(newItem);
TableResult result = table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

Any help on how to store the decimal in the published version of the app would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If any additional information is needed to solve this issue, just let me know.

Comment: Is your computer using the exact same language settings (Windows settings) as the server?

Comment: Notice that this wouldn't be a problem if you used ASP.NET MVC as it is supposed to be used (with a proper viewmodel with model binding) rather than hacking it with `Request["tbItemPrice"]`

Comment: Both language settings are for English (United Kingdom).

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto How could I best integrate the viewmodel?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Comment: hope you are using all financial fields as decimal instead of double.

Comment: @Girish brings up a very good point. double is a very bad type to use to represent money. It is not an exact number, it is an approximation. When you get into certain sizes of data you can begin to see small approximation errors occur. decimal or numeric represent accurate data when it comes to money.

Comment: I am using double, but only for validation reasons, no calculations are ever preformed. Decimals have to be converted to double to be stored into the table storage or else stay as a string until taken out.

Comment: @Jared Have you tried to [remote debug the WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio) to check the price value before insert into table?

Comment: @TomSun Yes, the remote debug still put the comma into the table storage entity, only the publish has yet to so far.

Comment: @Jared, It is very odd. I recommand that you could add some test code to write the table entity data into a file in the Azure server(D:\home\..) before insert into the table with your released version.